# When an eigenvalue is degenerate, are there always other operators which distinguishes the degenerate states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Familiarity with QM tells us that when an eigenvalue of an operator $\hat{A}$ is degenerate i.e. more than one eigenfunction of $\hat{A}$ has the same eigenvalue, there is usually another operator (or operators) $\hat{B}$ whose action on these eigenfunctions gives different eigenvalues. For example, $\hat{A}$ is the Hamiltonian operator of a free particle, and $\hat{B}$ could be the momentum operator of the free particle. Does such an operator $\hat{B}$ always exist whenever degeneracies are present (I mean is there a theorem of some kind)?

Comment: Well, if the dimension of some eigenspace of an eigenvalue of $A$ is larger than one, simply define the operator $B$ to have any orthonormal basis of this eigenspace as eigenvectors with different eigenvalues (and on the non-degenerate spaces of $A$ simply by as the identiy or zero or so). Or do you have any requirements on $B$ (and or $A$)?